# UIAlertView from Tab Button - No Internet Connection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.3

Looking for some help again...

I've currently got 2 sections of my app that need internet connection, 1 is a photo gallery through Flickr and the other a Twitter Feed, I was wondering if this is the correct code for the UIAlertView... I can get it working from a button but thats all!

```
{
-(void)didTap_roundedRectButton1:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
alertView.title = @"You are not connected to the Internet!";
alertView.message = @"Please check your connection and try again...";
[alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Also remember that iOS will post an alert for you if your app attempts to access a network resource while the connection is down for a reason such as the device being in airplane mode. In those cases you might not need to alert the user additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use this example as i have used it to check is there any network is available and device is connected to any one of the network it is alos available on the apple's developer example site
example link is [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/Reachability)

Comment: Bad link - here's tonymillion's Reachability on GitHub: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You are not connected to the Internet!" 
                                                  message:@"Please check your connection and try again..."
                                                 delegate:nil 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                        otherButtonTitles: nil];

  [alertView show];
  [alertView release];
```

and can you post the code how do you create the UIButton?

Comment: Sorry I think my question is wrong! I've almost finished my app but left out the 'No Internet Connection' errors Apple ask for when submitting, If I click on the 'Photo Gallery' in my app without the internet it crashes the app, not sure why? I thought I needed a UIAlertView thats checks the connection? Any help would be great guys...